# I have to automate PDF document in IE

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I never tried performing PDF. When I click on the view link the PDF open I have to save the document and verify,But not sure how to download the file because we don't have download option.

[image]

once i click on view PDF document open
[image]
this how it open

Comment: You used the pdfbox label. How does this question relate to Apache PDFBox?

Comment: I didn't use any, i tried to search google how to save pdf but all have different process mine is different so waiting for the help

Comment: So you added the PDFBox label to attract PDFBox devs thinking that they might be able to help. That's not how stackoverflow works and you wasted a few seconds of my life because this is a question about web application and the Adobe PDF plugin. Btw, why not use the disk logo (left middle) to save the file? Or the the right mouse key on "view" and then save? Or is this a pure javascript link?

Comment: sorry, this is my 1st time posting the question, and yes it is pure java script link.i think i can use keybord keys and save the file,

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can edit the headers in DMViewDocument.do and change the Content-Disposition from inline to attachment

Comment: Hi Verthosa, thanks for advice but i don't have access to modify the src content in DMViewDocument.do.can you please advice how to save pdf doc into local pc .using selenium web driver.